# How to mix child XML elements with text in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Consider the following XML:

```
<name stamped-on-monument="unknown" remarks="name 2001/12/20">
  0011953U556K
  <aka stamped-on-monument="unknown" remarks="">
    00153U556K
  </aka>
</name>
```

Is it acceptable to have "inner text" value and children in an element?

How can I define this in an XML Schema document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're describing [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#mixedContent), which can be specified via `mixed="true"` on `xs:complexType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="aka">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttrs"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttrs"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="commonAttrs">
    <xs:attribute name="stamped-on-monument"/>
    <xs:attribute name="remarks"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I now  see that Excel does not support mixed types, and thus cannot verify this. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do what you want

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string">
          <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="aka" type="xs:string">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:attribute name="stamped-on-monument" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                      <xs:attribute name="remarks" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                 <xs:attribute name="stamped-on-monument" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                 <xs:attribute name="remarks" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
             </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

Comment: You cannot have both a `type` attribute and a `complexType` element on the same element definition; what the OP is looking for is *mixed content*, and this is not the correct way to achieve it.

Comment: it was generated by http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html clearly it did a bad job, http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output does a much better job